# missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: npm

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
webpack &&
    cp -r i18n build/i18n &&
    cp -r core build/core &&
    cp -r views build/views &&
    cp -r styles build/styles &&
    find ./components -iname \"*.html\" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/ \\;
```

and it is returning following error message:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tracker-capture-app@26.0.10 build: `webpack && cp -r i18n 
build/i18n && cp -r core build/core && cp -r views build/views && cp -r 
styles build/styles && find ./components -iname "*.html" -exec echo '{}' 
./build/ \;`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tracker-capture-app@26.0.10 build script 'webpack && 
cp -r i18n build/i18n && cp -r core build/core && cp -r views build/views && 
cp -r styles build/styles && find ./components -iname "*.html" -exec echo 
'{}' ./build/ \;'.
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The first syntax error I noticed is  `\\;`. It should be `\;`, which is a literal semicolon `;` to end the `-exec` statement.
2. The directory needs​ a trailing slash, so that `find` looks inside of it.
3. And, as @steeldriver mentioned, `\"*.html\"` should be just `"*.html"`, unless you're looking for html files with quotes in their filenames.

So, in full:

```
find ./components/ -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/ \;
```

Comment: I suspect the `\"*.html\"` is over-escaped as well

Comment: i tried using this :-find ./components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R '{}' ./build/ \;...........it says :-skipping directory .                 and i even tried using:- find ./components -iname \"*.html\" -exec rsync -R ./build/ ; .....:- but unable to build html pages in my component folder

Comment: @SudikshaNagvanshi Ah, the directory needs a trailing slash. I updated my answer. BTW, you can use backticks in comments for `code formating`.

Comment: it give me an error   :$ npm run build
npm ERR! file E:\nodejs\prac\111\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.' at 9:160
npm ERR! ld/views && cp -r styles build/styles && find ./components/ -iname "*.html" -ex
npm ERR!                                                                      ^
npm ERR! File: E:\nodejs\prac\111\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.

Comment: That's not the same command.